# Element[joint:hinge] not defined in SDF

Tags: gazebo, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the URDF from here:

https://github.com/aurofable/ros/blob/master/art-experimental/urdf/navgroup.urdf

When I run "gzsdf print car.urdf" [or spawn in gazebo] I get:

Error [parser.cc:697] XML Element[joint:hinge], child of element[model] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[model]
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element [model]
Error [parser.cc:348] Unable to read element [sdf]  
Error [parser.cc:273] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error: SDF parsing the xml failed

It doesn't like the joint:hinge inside of the gazebo tag. (It won't let me post the code here.)

joint:hinge appears to be valid:

http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Gazebo-manual-0.8.0-pre1-html/group_gazebo_hinge_joint.html

Is this a version problem? Or the structure of the URDF? I have been searching all day and haven't found a solution.

I am running indigo and Gazebo 2.2.6

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259531/element%5Bjoint:hinge%5D-not-defined-in-sdf/) by [jsampson](https://answers.ros.org/users/30072/jsampson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-04-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jsampson](https://answers.ros.org/users/30072/jsampson/) on 2017-04-25**:
I loaded Kinetic on VMware under ubuntu16.04. That came with Gazebo 7.0.0. Now when I run "gz sdf -p car.urdf" it lists the [joint::hinge] as warnings instead of errors. The model will spawn in Gazebo, but the links don't seem to be connected correctly. I will play with it some more and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I gave up on the connect links and switched over to this project:
https://github.com/gKouros/ackermann_vehicle

---

Originally posted by [jsampson](https://answers.ros.org/users/30072/jsampson/) with karma: 26 on 2017-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0